# How to split a string with spaces into one element?

Tags: python, string, split, whitespace

When I have the string

```
 GJ 581 g      3.1     1.36     1.22     1.67     1.51     0.15      278      248
```

I want to split it so it becomes

`['GJ 581 g', '3.1', '1.36', '1.22', '1.67', '1.51', '0.15', '278', '248']`.

I tried using split which gives

`['GJ', '581', 'g', '3.1', '1.36', '1.22', '1.67', '1.51', '0.15', '278', '248']`.

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: maybe first you should use `.split('g')` to get first part, and later split on space.

Comment: or maybe you should join back first 3 elements `" ".join(data[:3])`

Comment: you could also check if there are spaces or tabs (because `split()` use both values). And if there are tabs then use `.split('\t')`

Comment: if you always has the same number of values then you can also do `.rsplit(maxsplit=8)`

Comment: if you read it from file to `pandas.DataFrame` then you can use `read_csv` with `sep="\s{2,}"` to separate when there is 2 or more spaces.

Comment: you can do the same with `regex` - `re.split('\s{2,}', text)`

Answer (score 2):

There is many possibilities.

If there is always 8 elements then you can use `right split` with `maxsplit`

```
data = text.rsplit(maxsplit=8)
```

You can also use `regex` to split when there is 2 or more spaces

```
import re

data = re.split('\s{2,}', text)
```

You may split on all spaces and later join back first 3 elements

```
data = text.split()

data = [" ".join(data[:3])] + data[3:]
```

You can also check if there are spaces or tabs - if there are tabs then you can use `.split("\t")`.

If first element always ends with `g` then you can `.split("g")` to get first part and rest, and later you can split rest on spaces

```
first, rest = text.split('g')
data = [first+"g"] + rest.split()
```

---

If you read data from file to `pandas.DataFrame` then you can use `read_csv()` and use regex as separator `sep="\s{2,}`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep="\s{2:}")
```

And if there are tabs then you can also use `sep='\t'`

Comment: Thank you for adding my answer to yours. I can delete mine now

Comment: @CtrlZ sorry, I start adding all ideas from my comments.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to split this on two spaces rather than just one so that entries with spaces are kept together:

```
*r, = filter(None,map(str.strip,s.split("  ")))

['GJ 581 g', '3.1', '1.36', '1.22', '1.67', '1.51', '0.15', '278', '248']
```